# Characterizing non-co-linearity

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, vectors

Let $\vec{V_1} ,\vec{V_2}$ be two vectors defined in a space.  We say that $\vec{V_1}$ and $\vec{V_2}$ are co-linear iff there exist a real number $k$ such that $\vec{V_1}=k \vec{V_2}$.  If I want to say that the two vectors are not co-linear then, is this claim true?

> **Claim:**
>   If $\vec{V_1} ,\vec{V_2}$ are not co-linear then $\vec{V_1}\neq k \vec{V_2}$ with $k$ real number.

Comment: The claim is somewhat ambiguous because it lacks a quantifier.  What you mean is there does not exist a real number $k$ such that $\vec{V_1} = k \vec{V_2}$.  Equivalently, for all real number $k$, $\vec{V_1} \ne k \vec{V_2}$.

Comment: BTW, the accepted spelling is collinear, not co-linear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Your "claim" is the contrapositive of the definition, hence automatically true.